# possible to set custom icon of FileAttachment Annotation in Adobe Reader

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, pdf, adobe-reader

I am working on PDF annotation app i added  File Attachment Annotation in PDF file but facing one issue how to set custom icon of File Attachment in Adobe Reader it provide default 4 types of icon in this image but my requirement is to  set   custom icon so it possible ??
please give me suggestion 
[image]